# Referential integrity - check referenced document exists before new document created

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Lets say we have reference documents:

```
{
   id: "1",
   type: "car",
   make: "Nissan",
   model: "Some Nissan Model"
   partitionKey: "vehicleDefinitions"
},
{
   id: "2",
   type: "truck",
   make: "Scania",
   model: "Some Scania Model"
   partitionKey: "vehicleDefinitions"
}
...
```

Now, we create new vehicle in one of our fleets, something like:

```
{
   id: "1",
   type: "fleetVehicle",
   partitionKey: "fleet_17_vehicles",
   vehicleDefinitionRefId: 2, //this references Scania truck definition above
   year: 2019,
   tiresChangeDate: ...
...
}
```

Obviously, our reference data (vehicles definitions) are in one partition and actual vehicles for actual fleets are all in their respective partitions defined as composite key based on `fleetId`.

Question is: when adding new vehicle to the fleet, how to make sure (atomically) that vehicle definition record is not deleted?

Checking in client app like:

1. first get reference document
2. if exists (as seen from application) create new vehicle in fleet

doesn't work since vehicle definition could theoretically be deleted between 1 and 2.

Possible solutions i can think of are:

1. Make a business rule that reference documents cannot be deleted (its ok, but i'd like to avoid it if possible).
2. Theoretically, putting reference documents (vehicle definitions) and actual vehicles in fleets into same partition would solve the problem since stored procedures are transactional per partition, but it effectively means putting all vehicles into same partition and that's not an option.

I don't like either.

Are there any other options?

PS.
Please don't focus too much on the domain in the example (fleet management). I've just made it up to illustrate case where referenced document could be deleted while creating new documents.
Its a broad, theoretical question, regardless of the domain in the example.

Comment: I don't know if you are aware of this and how this affects your question but the `id` is only unique within it's own partition. This means that even though a document has the same id with another one they are completely different documents and you won't get a clash if they have different partition key values.

Comment: The reason why I'm bringing this up is because if you try to directly read something by id you also need it's partition key value. If you don't have that then you can't know if it exists or not without querying. If you query, then it has to be a cross partition query which will tank your performance.

Comment: @NickChapsas hey, thanks for your comment. Yes i am aware of that and i know all partition keys at query time so its not an issue.